# Is it possible to have npm get a dependency from local files but fallback to a published package?

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, devops

I'm developing both an application and a package which it will depend on. I'd like to use git submodules to include the package in my dev environment and build using a published package from npm when I compile for production. What is the easiest way to achieve something like this?

Comment: I've seen the answer here and am hoping for something less fidgety. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499753/developing-an-npm-package-and-a-project-that-depends-on-it-at-the-same-time

Comment: "Only when B's API gets stable enough, publish it as a separate module and depend on it npm way." This is a black and white solution which requires messing with npm every time a change is made to the underlying package in dev environment once the package has been published. I'd like to be able to change the dependency continuously in my dev environment and then have either a flag or some other configuration option that gets the published package when I compile for QA/PROD.